# Improving Accuracy on Text Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, text-classification

I am trying to find a model for a text classification task. The number of my samples are around 4500 sentences of each sentence being approx 50 words length. The classes that i want to classify my text are 3, positive, negative and neutral. I used machine learning (SVM,RF,LR) and i got not more than 75% accuracy (i ve done the preprocessing part aswell). I would like to work a little bit with Deep Neural Nets and reccurent maybe but i dont know where to start. What are your suggestions in order to achieve maximum accuracy? and how much accuracy should i expect? (p.s I use python)

Comment: 4500 sentences is not a lot of data, especially for DNNs.
What did you do for the preprocessing?
Also, are your target classes balanced?

Answer (score 0):

4500 sentences, 50 words length each is quite not enough for deep architecture. You can try to figure it out, but I don't think it will work.
With this amount of data, I suggest you put more effort on parameter tuning and word embedding for the algorithm that you had tried (SVM, RF, ...). How did you represent your data in numerical space? A good embedding with not-state-of-the-art method can still show magnificent results.
For the question about expectation of accuracy, if I haven't seen the data, there is no way I could tell you that information. But, from my own experience, a 3-classes text classification problem, with not too long for each sentence, can be tackled with an accuracy ranging from 80 to 90%, or even 98%. It depends heavily on the essence of your data

Answer (score 0):

Positive/Negative/Neutral text/review classification is a pretty common task and there are a number of datasets on the web. You can use some of them and extend your training dataset. Or try to use pretrained model based on them.